Filament: Set Modal Title
In filament 3, how can I set custom view modal title? Like showing title "Member Info" instead of the default "View member".

 Tables\Actions\ViewAction::make()->label('Member Info')


I'll figured it this out by opening the vendor/filament/actions/src/ViewAction.php file.
You'll see that it uses a function called modalHeading (which comes from vendor/filament/actions/src/Concerns/CanOpenModal.php).
You can just override it:
->modalHeading('Member Info')

Then I also found it explained in the docs:
https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/actions/modals#customizing-the-modals-heading-description-and-submit-action-label

to change the title of the page, I made this way:
use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Htmlable;    

public function getHeading(): string
    {
        return __('NEW HEADING');
    }

    public function getTitle(): string | Htmlable
    {
        return __('NEW TITLE');
    } 

to change the breadcrumb and navigation label I use this code on the resource page:
protected static ?string $navigationLabel = 'NEW TITLE LABEL NAVIGATION';    
    public static function getBreadcrumb(): string
    {
        return 'NEW TITLE BREADCRUMB';
    }

https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/panels/pages#customizing-the-page-title
